# Android sqlitedatabase no such table

Tags: android, sqlite

When adressing my database in my SQLiteOpenHelper-class, I get a 'no such table' error, even though the onCreate method gets called eand I create the table-structure in that method.

```
public class BVCDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Increment when db schema changes
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BVC.db";

    private static final String INTEGER_TYPE = " INTEGER";
    private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
    private static final String COMMA_SEP = ",";
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
        "CREATE TABLE " + Games.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
        Games._ID + TEXT_TYPE + " PRIMARY KEY," +
        Games.COLUMN_NAME_HOME + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
        Games.COLUMN_NAME_GUESTS + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
        Games.COLUMN_NAME_TIMESTAMP + INTEGER_TYPE + "); " +
        "CREATE TABLE " + Sets.TABLE_NAME + " (" + 
        Sets._ID + INTEGER_TYPE + " PRIMARY KEY," +
        Sets.COLUMN_NAME_GAME_CODE + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP + 
        Sets.COLUMN_NAME_HOME + INTEGER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP + 
        Sets.COLUMN_NAME_GUESTS + INTEGER_TYPE + "); " +
        "CREATE TABLE " + Teams.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
        Teams._ID + TEXT_TYPE + " PRIMARY KEY," +
        Teams.COLUMN_NAME_NAME + TEXT_TYPE + "); " + 
    private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES =
        "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Games.TABLE_NAME
        + "; DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Sets.TABLE_NAME
        + "; DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Teams.TABLE_NAME

    public BVCDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
        Log.i("BVCDbHelper", "Table structures created in " + db.getPath());
    }
```

The error:

`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: team (code 1): , while compiling: 
SELECT _id, teamName FROM team WHERE _id=? OR _id=?`

The onCreate executes without issues, and doesn't generate an error. A method that generates this error tries to insert a game, and it doesn't return such an error when I insert a game. What could be the cause of this?

```
/** Create team */
public void addTeam(Team t){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Teams._ID, t.getCode());
    values.put(Teams.COLUMN_NAME_NAME, t.getName());

    insert(Teams.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
}
/** General insert method */
private void insert(String tableName, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.insertOrThrow(tableName, nullColumnHack, values);
    db.close();
}
```

Or should I try to create my tables using separate statements (and execSQL methods) for each table instead of one?

**Update:** I needed to create the tables one by one. This solves my issue. I now have ArrayLists with the create and delete entries, which I loop over when I need to create or delete my structures.

Comment: You are going wrong in create query. you need to provide space between your column name and column type

Comment: Need space after the comma:.. PRIMARY KEY," +
        Games.COLUMN_NAME_HOME + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_S ..

Comment: The types have a space as a prefix, so there are always spaces between column names and column types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add space between your `Column Name` and `Column Type` into your `Create Query` like:

```
  private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
    "CREATE TABLE " + Games.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
    Games._ID + " "+TEXT_TYPE + " PRIMARY KEY, " +
    Games.COLUMN_NAME_HOME + " "+TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
    Games.COLUMN_NAME_GUESTS + " "+TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
    Games.COLUMN_NAME_TIMESTAMP + " "+INTEGER_TYPE + "); " +
    "CREATE TABLE " + Sets.TABLE_NAME + " (" + 
    Sets._ID +" "+INTEGER_TYPE + " PRIMARY KEY, " +
    Sets.COLUMN_NAME_GAME_CODE +" "+TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP + 
    Sets.COLUMN_NAME_HOME +" "+INTEGER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP + 
    Sets.COLUMN_NAME_GUESTS " "+INTEGER_TYPE + "); "
```

Here i saw you just demo. Correct by your self.

Comment: The types have a space as a prefix, so there are always spaces between column names and column types.

Comment: @Diëgo why are you creating this table into one String?. create one by one

Comment: @M D this was indeed the issue, I just tried it myself and the error is gone :-) got another one instead, but I should be able to handle that one.